# How to specify which key to use for GnuPG sign/verify?

Tags: gnupg, digital-signature

We have a package that we're trying to create a detached signature for, to ensure the other end can be confident it's from us.

I know how to specify the correct identities when creating a key-pair since `gpg --gen-key` specifically asks for the identity. I also know how to export the public and private keys for a given identity:

```
gpg --export             me@somewhere.com --armour --output key.public
gpg --export-secret-keys me@somewhere.com --armour --output key.private
```

and that the public key should be distributed and imported at the receiving end for verification:

```
gpg --import key.public
```

However (my first question), I don't know how to specify a *particular* key-pair in the situation where a single identity may have more than one. For example, say we have two key-pairs for `me@somewhere.com`, one for software install packages and one for secure shell access. How would I go about exporting only one of those pairs?

My second question has more to do with generating and verifying a signature over a document.

How does the command:

```
gpg --detach-sig inputDoc --output detachedSigDoc
```

actually know which key-pair to use for creating the signature? I see there's a `--local-user` which allows you to "specify a user id to use for signing" but how does that work when there are multiple key-pairs for a given identity?

In any case, there doesn't appear to be an equivalent operation for the `gpg --verify` option so how can we specify the key-pair to use when *checking* the source of the file?

For what it's worth, we're using GnuPG version 1 since we're on an embedded system.

Answer (score 2):

**Signing:** I don't recall if this is a change, but v2 man page says either `--local-user/-u` *or* `--default-key` can specify the signing key. Although not explicitly stated here, anywhere you need to identify a key you can use either the userid (conventionally but not necessarily an email address) or the keyid. If you have multiple keys for the same userid, **use the keyid** to specify uniquely.

**Verifying:** the keyid is in the signature packet, and the (public) key is found **automatically** -- unless you don't have that key in your keyring in which case it says `Can't check signature: No public key` and if you want to check you have to get and import the key.

PS: How on earth do you use a GPG/PGP key for SSH? AFAIK neither OpenSSH or commercial (Tectia) SSH can use PGP format keys.